# Why would binary asteroids created from YORP spin-up tend to have mutual orbits coplanar to their heliocentric orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, asteroid

[Vavilov, *et al.*, "Evidence for widely-separated binary asteroids recorded by craters on Mars", *Icarus* 383 115045 (2022)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103522001579#b57)
says on page 8 that binary asteroids created through the [Yarkovsky–O'Keefe–Radzievskii–Paddack effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky%E2%80%93O%27Keefe%E2%80%93Radzievskii%E2%80%93Paddack_effect) [(YORP)](https://www.planetary.org/articles/20141211-the-yorp-effect-and-bennu) induced spin-up tends to create systems whose mutual orbit is coplanar to the heliocentric orbit. Why is this?

Comment: Try asking on the astronomy stack exchange. Tenuous connection to space exploration.

Comment: Ok, should I delete this now?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40490/16685 Note that the momentum of the incoming sunlight is in the heliocentric orbit plane.